# Fill selection (flood fill implement)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array, implementation, flood-fill

I'm doing a simple paper.io remake, but I don't have any idea how can I implement flood fill algorithm.

I have an 30x30 array which stores cell object (it has info about cell owner/tail owner). When player gets back to his own territory, his tail is assigned as owned cells, but how to fill selected space - between his territory and tail (like on image).
[image]

Comment: Im not sure if you have implementation trouble on flood fill or you have trouble understanding how it works. Anyways, here is a truly great resource for the understanding, with relevant animations. http://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html#breadth-first-search

Comment: I understand how it works, but idk what is the best way to get starting coordinates. Player can draw something like this http://i.imgur.com/PFUpzi4.jpg In this case i have to use flood fill 3 times. When the block is tail or player territory it ends flood fill. So i don't know how can i get starting coordinates to fill it ;v